# Multiple File Upload using dropzone and with other forms fields with FormValidation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, dropzone.js, formvalidation-plugin

[image]This is the image of form which I have designed in my project Now my requirement is to upload multiple files and with other form values over a single backend call.

```
<script>
<form class="form-horizontal" name="addColorForm" id="addColorForm"
                          enctype="multipart/form-data"
                          method="POST">
  //Colour Name and Code fileds
  //Files Uploader Plugin  (Dropzone)
 <input type="file" name="artworkFiles[]" style="visibility: hidden"/>
</form>
```

Now my script part

```
 <script>
    var validCode = function () { // my custom validation };
        FormValidation.validators.validCode = validCode;
        FormValidation.formValidation(
            document.getElementById('addColorForm'),
            {
                fields: {
                    colorName: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: '${message(code:"blank.error.message", default:"This field must be entered")}'
                            },
                        }
                    },
                  },
                plugins: { //Learn more: https://formvalidation.io/guide/plugins
                    trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
                    // Bootstrap Framework Integration
                    bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap(),
                    // Validate fields when clicking the Submit button
                    submitButton: new FormValidation.plugins.SubmitButton(),
                    // Submit the form when all fields are valid
                    // defaultSubmit: new FormValidation.plugins.DefaultSubmit(),
                }
            }
        ).on('core.form.valid', function () {
            saveColor();
        });
    
        function saveColor() {
            var url = "url";
            var form = $("#createArtworkForm");
            var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {},
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                error: function () { }
            });
        }

   var artworkColorsFiles = $('#kt_dropzone').dropzone({
    url: "https://www.google.com", // Set the url for your upload script location
    paramName: "media", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 40, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    accept: function (file) {
        //Logic to add multiple files in an input type hidden which is declared above
        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        fileReader.onloadend = function () {

            let content = fileReader.result;
            $('#artworkFiles').val(content);
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        }
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-complete");
    }
 
});

</script>
```

**My questions is how to implement this or how should i add my all files(max 3) in a input type file field declared as visibility hidden.**

Answer (score 0):

The same I did in my project here is the code hope it will help you.
you have to use the dropzone function to send file and form data in **sendingmultiple**  function you have to add a loop through your formdata `enter code here`

```
var data = $("form#OpportunityForm").serializeArray();
                $.each(data, function (key, el) {
                        .append(el.name, el.value);
                });



 $(document).ready(function () {
        zdrop = new Dropzone('#dropzone', {
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveOpportunity", "Masters")',
            maxFiles: 500,
            maxFilesize: 300,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            removeFilePromise: function () {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
                    console.log(rand);
                    if (rand == 0) reject('didnt remove properly');
                    if (rand > 0) resolve();
                });
            },
            sendingmultiple: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                var data = $("form#OpportunityForm").serializeArray();
                $.each(data, function (key, el) {
                        .append(el.name, el.value);
                });
                debugger
                $("form#OpportunityForm").find("input[type=file]").each(function (index, field) {
                    const file = field.files[0];
                    formData.append('itemfile', file);
                });

            },
            successmultiple: function (file, responseText) {
                jQuery('form#OpportunityForm').find('textarea, input').each(function () {
                    jQuery(this).val('');
                });
                clear();
                swal.fire("Opportunity Details Saved!", "Opportunity details Saved Successfully!", "success");
                OpportunityMstList();
                GetOpportunityMstList();
                location.reload();
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
            },
        });
```

after adding this on the form submit button click you have to add this for creating blob file when you post data without image file.

```
  jQuery(document).on('click', 'button#saveOpportunity', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#OpportunityForm").validate().form()) {
        if (zdrop.files.length == 0) {
            var blob = new Blob();
            blob.upload = { 'chunked': zdrop.defaultOptions.chunking };
            zdrop.uploadFile(blob); // just submit the form
        } else if (zdrop.getRejectedFiles().length > 0) {
            alert("The attached file is invalid");
        } else {
            zdrop.processQueue();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: $.each has errors

Comment: please debug your code and check are you getting form data or not?

Comment: I updated the code on the form submit button you have to Create a blob file if the file is not selected.